# Matrix not inserting all combinations?

Tags: java, matrix, combinations

Here is my matrix of subjects ....  now I want to make conditionality between subjects

```
        mat     pro     
mat     null    null    
pro     null    null
```

for example on subject math i inserted subjects value for `semester =1`     on subject `programing` i put `semester = 4`    so I want to fill this matrix with "`yes`",     only if the `semester` of first subject is greater than semester on the second subject  and "`no`" if is not...     now problem that I have is that I can enter conditionalities for combinations:

```
math - math , which would be "no"
math - programing , which would be "no"
programing - programing , which would be "no"
```

and this looks like this when program is done:

```
        mat     pro     
mat     no      no  
pro     no      no
```

but I dont have this combination asked to put conditionality:
programing - math , which would be "yes"
and it should probably look like this:

```
        mat     pro     
mat     no      no  
pro     yes     no
```

how do I make this happen? any idea?

here is my code:

```
public void makeGraph() {

    matrix = new String[subjects.size()][subjects.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < matrix.length; j++) {

            System.out.println("Enter conditionality between subjects: " + subjects.get(i).getName() + ", and "
                    + subjects.get(j).getName());

            boolean conditioned = s.nextBoolean();

            if (conditioned == true) {
                if (subjects.get(i).getSemester() > subjects.get(j).getSemester()) {
                    matrix[i][j] = "yes";
                    matrix[j][i] = "yes";
                } else {    
                        matrix[i][j] = "no";
                        matrix[j][i] = "no";    
                }
            } else {
                matrix[i][j] = "no";
                matrix[j][i] = "no";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is the link to pastebin I've solved it.
[Solution](https://pastebin.com/PvWurdBc)

Comment: You post was so bad written, please make an effort ..

Comment: @azro I'm sorry I knew that but I couldn't get it, it didn't work for me when  tried to write it correctly.

Comment: If my solution helped, could you please accept it by clicking on the grey check mark next to my answer, making it green? Also, a click on the arrow up next to my answer would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @Assafs I didn't even look at you answer..just saw it when I finished solution ...now I see what you meant in the answer is the same thing that I was thinking, it was a good exercise I guess  hahaha and yes I will click check mark and arrow:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you assign the matrix. When Programming vs Math is on the scale and you choose to compare, you assign the same value to [i][j] as you do to [j][i]. That is incorrect. One should be set to no, and the other to yes, since one asks if Math has more semesters than Programming and the other asks if Programming has more semesters than Math. Since you're looking for greater and not greater-equals, then one of these questions being "yes" means the other is "no".

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it you can check out the code:

```
public void makeGraph() {

    matrix = new String[subjects.size()][subjects.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < matrix.length; j++) {

            boolean conditioned;

            if(subjects.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(subjects.get(j).getName())){
                conditioned=false;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Enter conditionality between subjects: " + subjects.get(i).getName() + ", and "
                        + subjects.get(j).getName());
                conditioned = s.nextBoolean();
            }

            if (conditioned == true) {

                if (subjects.get(i).getSemester() > subjects.get(j).getSemester()) {
                    matrix[i][j] = "yes";
                    matrix[j][i] = "no";
                }else if(subjects.get(i).getSemester()<subjects.get(j).getSemester()){

                    System.out.println("Enter conditionality between subjects: " + subjects.get(j).getName() + ", and "
                            + subjects.get(i).getName());
                    conditioned = s.nextBoolean();
                    matrix[i][j] = "no";
                    matrix[j][i] = "yes";   
                }else{  
                    matrix[i][j] = "no";
                    matrix[j][i] = "no";    
                }
            } else {
                matrix[i][j] = "no";
            }
        }
    }
}
```